# Vue - Listen to dynamically created channel name

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm trying to integrate Laravel-Vue-Pusher based notification and [laravel's broadcasting documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#concept-overview) has been very helpful.

So we create an laravel `event`, `trigger and broadcast` it on a `Pusher` channel.

On the Javascript side, we use `Echo` to listen for event broadcasts.

Here's some example-code for from the documentation:

```
Echo.private(`order.${orderId}`)
    .listen('ShippingStatusUpdated', (e) => {
        console.log(e.update);
    });
```

I tried using it in Vue and it threw an `ReferenceError: orderId is not defined`.

On the Laravel side, here's the `event` that's broadcasting it on that channel:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('order.'.$this->order->id);
}
```

Event is fired successfully and it also gets logged in Pusher Dashboard.

But i'm unable to figure out why i'm getting missing `orderId` error in Vue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ...do you have a variable called `orderId`?

Comment: Nope. I'm assuming when i call `return new PrivateChannel('order.'.$this->order->id);` the `orderId` should be automatically populated with the passed `$this->order->id`. Isn't it?

Comment: `orderId` is a client-side javascript variable.  Laravel broadcasts a message on the channel `order.6`, but your client JS needs to know to listen to `order.6` also.  It would be part of your front end logic.  You could also broadcast on `orders` and listen on `orders` without using an ID, that would work for a channel that isn't model specific. If the kitchen reports "Order 6 is ready!" but you don't have your receipt and know your number, you aren't getting your chicken tenders.

Comment: Then i'll need to figure out a way to "Authorizing Channels"